# stop_words for new version 2014.5.26

Tags: python

I am updating my stopwords for the new version `stop-words2014.5.26`, because I want to use the arabic stopwords. I am working in Anaconda. after I downloaded and installed the stopwords, the following error has appeared:

```
from stop_words import get_stop_words
stop=set(get_stop_words('english'))
<ipython-input-15-47cdc7fed487> in <module>()
```

This line

```
stop=set(get_stop_words('english'))
```

throws this error:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stop_words-2014.5.26-py3.5.egg\stop_words\__init__.py
in get_stop_words(language)
     21     with open('{0}{1}.txt'.format(STOP_WORDS_DIR, language)) as lang_file:
     22         lines = lang_file.readlines()
---> 23         return [str(line.strip()).decode('utf-8') for line in lines]

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stop_words-2014.5.26-py3.5.egg\stop_words\__init__.py
in <listcomp>(.0)
     21     with open('{0}{1}.txt'.format(STOP_WORDS_DIR, language)) as lang_file:
     22         lines = lang_file.readlines()
---> 23         return [str(line.strip()).decode('utf-8') for line in lines]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

I update the stop words version to the new one 2015,then every thing is working

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = set(stopwords.words('arabic'))
stop
{'،',
```

'أ',
 'ا',
 'اثر',
 'اجل',
 'احد',
 'اخرى',